# Eclipse RCP build - Unresolved requirement: com.sun.jna

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I just installed Eclipse 2022-06 (4.24.0) and built and export default RCP application product.
When I try to run this product in windows I get error in log file listed below. (in Eclipse IDE environment it runs perfectly).

It looks like library com.sun.jna is missing... But it included in required plug-ins.
It exists in config.ini and plugins folder of built product as well...

I spent two days trying to solve this issue and ran out of ides already...

```
!SESSION 2022-08-16 14:25:08.798 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=18.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 4 0 2022-08-16 14:25:09.361
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt [42]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"; bundle-version="0.16.500.v20220506-1520"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [44]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.2.100.v20211001-1648"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.urischeme [64]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-version="0.9.1"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-version="0.15.500.v20220511-1638"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [43]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.16.500.v20220506-1520"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1840)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1745)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

Comment: What version is the com.sun.jna you are including? The code is looking for at least 5.8.0 and less that 6.0.0. Version 5.8.0 is included in Eclipse 4.20 through 4.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As greg-449 suggests problem was with version of com.sun.jna...
Version 4.5.1 was included by default instead of 5.8.0.

So, to solve this, I added version requirements for com.sun.jna in *.product file "Contents" tab.